# Conditional OR not working as expected

Tags: apex, visualforce, conditional

I am not sure what I am missing, I am trying to execute something only if the value of 2 parameters are not empty. So if 1 or both are empty, excecute code a, if both values are not empty, excecute code B.
My code looks like this:

```
system.debug('@@ val1: ' + val1 + ' val2: ' + val2);
if(val1 != '' || val2 != ''){
    //CODE A
    //CODE: I dont understand why it is never getting here, even if either or both values are empty
}else{
    //CODE B
}
```

my debug log print

```
DEBUG|@@ val1:  val2:
```

It is wrong in apex to have a conditional OR ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

possibly the variables are holding null or white space instead of empty string.. Its always better to use the [string methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) isBlank , isNotBlank

```
if(String.isNotBlank(val1)  || String.isNotBlank(val2)){
    //CODE A
}else{
    //CODE B
}
```

oh and it seems you want CODE A to run if one or both the values are empty..

then you just need to check for **==** instead of **!=** (or use **isBlank** method instead of **isNotBlank** method)

```
if(String.isBlank(val1)  || String.isBlank(val2)){
    //CODE A
}else{
    //CODE B
}
```